# ASP.NET API Key's case is messed up

Tags: asp.net, api, serialization, key

I use ASP.NET Core 3.1

I want my API to return some data which I format as JSON.

For some reason one sub-object that I want to return is a class instance, with properties formatted as UPPERCASE_SNAKE_CASE.

I expect my response to give me data formatted like this :

```
{
    "user": {
        "USER_ID": 1,
        "USER_CODE": "xxx",
        "EMAIL": "myemail@domain.com"
    }
}
```

What I get instead is that some characters before the underscore char are in lowercase :

```
{
    "user": {
        "useR_ID": 1,
        "useR_CODE": "xxx",
        "email": "myemail@domain.com"
    }
}
```

In my Startup.cs file I use the following to format :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        ...
    }
```

I tried to add this line I read on other posts :

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

Which didnt change anything.

I don't want all my keys to change into UPPERCASE_SNAKE_CASE, because I am using camelCase, but I want the App to follow how the Key is written in code. When I use a debugger, keys are displayed as I want them to be, it's only in the client part (Angular or Postman) that the keys are messed up.

Comment: What does your class look like? And the action method? Do you have any other JSON configuration?

Comment: my user class is made with uppcarcase snakecase properties ; for example : public string USER_ID {get; set;}

The Api returns an IActionResult so I can do  return Ok(data)

Comment: Have you tried adding `[JsonProperty("USER_ID")]` style attributes to your class properties?

Comment: Ok this is exactly what I was looking for, I used this in previous projects but I just forgot it , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding [JsonProperty("USER_ID")] style attributes to your class properties? –
DavidG
Mar 2 at 11:43